# PForDelta implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, implementation

I was wondering if there is any implementation for PFD-compression algorithm for python or if there is a library for it. I have checked google search and I found some implementations for c/java .

Thanks in advance.

I also want to ask, can I run pfordelta for unsorted data, because all the implementations I saw so far are for sorted arrays.

["Java Implementation"](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/bulkpostings/lucene/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/pfor2/PForDelta.java)

["C implementation"](https://github.com/diegocaro/compression/blob/master/pfordelta.c)

Comment: You might want to [write your own C bindings](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#C.2FC.2B-.2B-). I can't imagine this to run any kind of fast in pure Python. I think a very thin wrapper based on `dlopen` and `ctypes` would work nicely.

Comment: Writing these bit-manipulating algorithms in Python is going to be slow for any practical uses. Only do that for learning purposes and then you probably don't need an existing implementation, do it on your own. Also, the "delta" part in the name implies sorted data, because you are taking advantage of the fact that the deltas are small numbers. It doesn't work efficiently without that.